# flutter text widget not displaying the variable ı meant it to display

Tags: flutter, widget

Where ı got the variable

[image: 1]

when ı want to print the variable it works but when ı try to show it on screen is doesn't display anything. any idea why and the variable isn't null ı printed it on the terminal and it actually worked

ı tried to write in a list tile and when that didn't work ı put it in a row but thatdidint worked either

Comment: can you post the full code of the widget ( preferably in your question not as an image ), and show the displayed UI that is missing the text

Answer (score 0):

You did not given any example of your doing. so can not understand what kind of variable you are talking about.

If your variable in integer then try '${var}.toString()' for display

```dart
int intValue = 1;
String stringValue = intValue.toString();
```